# Unable to access Open Data Cube database through Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, postgresql, jupyter-notebook, open-data-cube

I am trying to access the product added in Open Data Cube database through Jupyter notebook. I'm using [this demo notebook](https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-notebooks/blob/master/Demo_Notebook.ipynb). But I'm not able to connect to the database.
The below line showing the error.

`dc = datacube.Datacube(app = 'my_app', config = 'C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/13/data/datacube.conf')`

The error is,

```
OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "'localhost'
db_username: postgres
db_password: Metamorphosis" to address: Unknown host
```

[image]

As a workaround, I have tried to connect to the database manually, with the following commands which didn't produce any error.

```
import datacube
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="datacube", user="postgres", password="Metamorphosis")

dc = datacube.Datacube(conn)
```

But after this, when I'm trying to list the products, present on the database with `list_of_products = dc.list_products()` command, I'm getting error as,

> AttributeError: 'psycopg2.extensions.connection' object has no attribute 'products'

[image]

I'm using Windows 8.1, have created a database using PostgreSQL, trying to access the indexed Landsat 8 data.

Comment: You seem to have very old version of Datacube installed 0.0.0 ? As opposed to the latest 1.8.3. https://pypi.org/project/datacube/. Could you also check DB connection via psql and if CLI commands like `datacube product list` work ?

Comment: @whatnick I installed the latest version of Datacube, but still, getting the same errors. Also, I am able to connect to the database via psql, but `datacube product list` shows no output at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem. Turns out I was not indexing data to Open Data Cube in the proper way.

Please see [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/404713/data-indexing-problem-with-open-data-cube).