# Data indexing problem with Open Data Cube

Tags: postgresql, open-data-cube

I'm trying to index the LISS-3 (Resourcesat) products to Open-Data-Cube. I'm connecting to the database (datacube) through the Anaconda prompt after activating the virtual environment (please see the code below). After adding the YAML file, the `datacube product list` shows no output.

**Is there anything wrong with my indexing procedure?**

```
(base) C:\Users\user>conda activate cubeenv

(cubeenv) C:\Users\user>cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin

(cubeenv) C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin>psql -U postgres
Password for user postgres:
psql (13.3)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \connect datacube
You are now connected to database "datacube" as user "postgres".
datacube=# datacube product add F:/LISS3/L3_20oct09/product_definition_L3_20oct09.yml
datacube-# datacube dataset add F:/LISS3/L3_20oct09/product_documents_L3_20oct09.yml
datacube-# datacube product list
datacube-#
```

I'm using Windows 8.1, have created a database using PostgreSQL.
The YAML files are attached.

1. [Product definition file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PK2Uu98XTx_dQyLcYTZXOaNdkBeXNpHr/view?usp=sharing)
2. [Dataset document file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MG1e6k4SrlZedQ2gIiKerZ6Rqf7jV1Yn/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Datacube is a python cli tool. Not a PostgreSQL command. Which how-to are you following ? Please drop out of the PostgreSQL prompt and setup environment variables to initialize the schema with 'datacube init' and continue from there.

Comment: @whatnick I'm not following any particular how-to. I got advice from a colleague that this method might work. Can you please explain the method you are saying? I'm new to this and really stuck with this part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use Postgres, you need to terminate a line with `;`. If you do that, you'll get an error message because the `datacube` command is not a Postgres command.

To run Datacube, you do it just from the command prompt. So run `datacube system check` instead of `psql` to see if it's working ok.

Then you need to run `datacube system init` to set up the DB.

And then you can add products and datasets by doing `datacube product add <path-to-yaml>` or `datacube dataset add <path-to-dataset-yaml>`.

This is all [documented here](https://datacube-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Thank you. It worked.